# Leaking Webservice Completed events?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, event-handling

In my C# application I have a service reference where I do the same call over and over again.

```
void GetData()
{
  var request = new GetDataRequest { someData = "blabla" } ;
  service.GetDataCompleted += (sender, args) => 
  {
      // do something; i'm afraid that this is executed multiple times, as GetData() is called multiple times
  }
  service.GetDataAsync(request);
}

void GetData2()
{
  var request = new GetDataRequest { someData = "blabla2" } ;
  service.GetDataCompleted += (sender, args) => 
  {
      // do something different here!
  }
  service.GetDataAsync(request);
}
```

I have the suspicion that this leaks somehow, since i register a new event handler every time.
Is it true, and if yes, how can i avoid that?

Comment: Do you instantiate `service` object many times or just once?

Comment: Then you should subscribe the event handler right there just once.

Comment: @YK1: that is what i also thought already. but it leaves one problem: what if i want to call the request with different handlers each time?

Comment: You need to provide more information based on your edit.  As YK1 indicated, if you're calling GetData *multiple* times and only want the event to fire *once*, it would be helpful to understand how you're calling GetData.

Comment: @wilso132 ok, i have edited my question and added another call to the same service request, which should execute different code. i hope this illustrates my question.

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer; as YK1 suggested, I think you should move your event registration out of these methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
void GetData()
{
  var request = new GetDataRequest { someData = "blabla" } ;

  EventHandler handler = null; 
  handler = (sender, args) => 
  {
      // do something; i'm afraid that this is executed multiple times, as GetData() is called multiple times

      //remove itself
      service.GetDataCompleted -= handler;
  };

  service.GetDataCompleted += handler;
  service.GetDataAsync(request);
}

void GetData2()
{
  var request = new GetDataRequest { someData = "blabla2" } ;
  EventHandler handler = null; 

  handler = (sender, args) => 
  {
      // do something different here!

      //remove itself
      service.GetDataCompleted -= handler;
  };

  service.GetDataCompleted += handler;
  service.GetDataAsync(request);
}
```

**EDIT** : About synchronizing calls only to its handler: If you call `GetData2()` immediately followed by `GetData()` you will get unpredictable results from above code. Mostly, both handlers will be called for both requests.

The simplest solution for this is to have separate `service` proxy object per `GetDataX()` method. This way you can make both requests concurrently.

However, if you are forced to use only a single proxy object, and make concurrent requests - a wrong handler could be called. One option is you can use a `UserState` object to identify your request, so even if wrong handler is called, it can detect that its being called for the wrong request.

```
void GetData()
{
  var request = new GetDataRequest { someData = "blabla" } ;

  Guid userState = Guid.NewGuid();

  EventHandler<GetDataCompletedEventArgs> handler = null; 
  handler = (sender, args) => 
  {
      if (userState.Equals(args.UserState)) 
      {
          // do something; i'm afraid that this is executed multiple times, as GetData() is called multiple times

          //remove itself
          service.GetDataCompleted -= handler;
      }
  };

  service.GetDataCompleted += handler;
  service.GetDataAsync(request, userState);
}

void GetData2()
{
  var request = new GetDataRequest { someData = "blabla2" } ;

  Guid userState = Guid.NewGuid();

  EventHandler<GetDataCompletedEventArgs> handler = null; 
  handler = (sender, args) => 
  {
      if (userState.Equals(args.UserState)) 
      {
          // do something different here!

          //remove itself
          service.GetDataCompleted -= handler;
      }
  };

  service.GetDataCompleted += handler;
  service.GetDataAsync(request, userState);
}
```

Now if you make concurrent requests and even if both handlers are called for both requests, only the right code for the right request will run inside the `if` condition.

In case you don't want to use `UserState` there are some ways you can synchronize the calls so that handlers don't step over each other. Following is one non-blocking way using `Tasks` that makes sure requests happen one after another.

```
Task<GetDataResponse> GetData()
{
  var src = new TaskCompletionSource<GetDataResponse>();     

  var request = new GetDataRequest { someData = "blabla" } ;
  EventHandler handler = null; 
  handler = (sender, args) => 
  {
      // do something; i'm afraid that this is executed multiple times, as GetData() is called multiple times

      src.SetResult(args.Result);

      //remove itself
      service.GetDataCompleted -= handler;
  };

  service.GetDataCompleted += handler;
  service.GetDataAsync(request);

  return src.Task;
}

Task<GetDataResponse> GetData2()
{
  var src = new TaskCompletionSource<GetDataResponse>();

  var request = new GetDataRequest { someData = "blabla2" } ;
  EventHandler handler = null; 

  handler = (sender, args) => 
  {
      // do something different here!

      src.SetResult(args.Result);

      //remove itself
      service.GetDataCompleted -= handler;
  };

  service.GetDataCompleted += handler;
  service.GetDataAsync(request);

  return src.Task;

}
```

And in the calling method, you make sure they are called one after another:

```
GetData().ContinueWith( t => GetData2() );
```

Comment: thanks, but couldnt that run into a race condition? where one requests takes longer than the other? isnt it somehow possible to get the request in the handler?

Comment: @clamp: well you didn't mention you wanted thread safety - I assumed you were synchronizing the requests somehow calling them one by one. OK - yeah, if you call `GetData()` followed by `GetData2()` immediately, sure you will get unpredictable results - mostly like both handlers will be called for both requests. Simple solution is that you have separate `service` object per `GetDataX()` - however there could be other ways to synchronize this. You tell me your requirement and I'll try to update my answer. (Also, are you using .NET 4.5?)

Comment: sry, i mentioned that thread safety in the other answers comment, which got deleted meanwhile.  i am forced to use .NET 4.

Comment: @clamp: updated answer with `userState` option - that might be what you want.